# c# Regex.Match does not match .Net Regex Tester results

Tags: c#, regex

I need to restrict users to passwords with at least 8 characters and the mixture of lower case, upper case, number and special character. I have used .Net Regex Test website for my tests and came to the following solution. From the two links below you can see that [mer220d#](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5CW%29%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5CS%5D%7B8%2C%7D%24&i=mer220d%23) has no match, but [Mer220d#](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5CW%29%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5CS%5D%7B8%2C%7D%24&i=Mer220d%23) matches perfectly, yet in my .Net code, which uses exactly the same Regex, both of them return true.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace BOR.Security.CheckConstraints
{
    public class CheckPasswordConstraint
    { 

        public static bool passwordValidation(string passwordToCheck)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)[a-zA-Z0-9\S]{8,}$";
            Match m = Regex.Match(passwordToCheck.TrimEnd(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return m.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you advise what I am missing, please?

Comment: They are not exactly the same as your code, remove `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, due to which `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])` = `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` (i.e. it just requires 1 letter)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that should be the answer

Comment: Besides, `[a-zA-Z0-9\S]` = `\S`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I have replaced [a-zA-Z0-9\S] with \S and it works in .Net Regex Test as per your advice, yet removing RegexOptions.IgnoreCase didn't solve the issue - I still receive true in my C# code for mer220d#. Is there a way to implicitly say NOT to IgnoreCase, please?

Comment: `
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ENV.Security.CheckConstraints
{
    public class CheckPasswordConstraint
    { 
        public static bool passwordValidation(string passwordToCheck)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)[\S]{8,}$";
            Match m = Regex.Match(passwordToCheck.TrimEnd(), pattern);
        return m.Success;
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: What do you mean by "implicitly say NOT to `IgnoreCase`"? Do you have any control over the option, the code? If not, try `@"(?-i)^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)\S{8,}$"` - the `(?-i)` will force the pattern to be treated in a case sensitive way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have used your pattern, but to no avail - it still returns Success = true. Now my code looks like 
`string pattern = @"(?-i)^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)\S{8,}$";
            Match m = Regex.Match(passwordToCheck.TrimEnd(), pattern);`

By NOT I have meant if it is possible to force to apply to check if the case is upper case.

Comment: @KDWolf I do not understand a thing now. **What are your requirements?** `(?=.*[a-z])` requires at least one lowercase ASCII, `(?=.*[A-Z])` requires at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter, `(?=.*\d)` requires at least 1 digit and `(?=.*\W)` requires at least 1 char other than any Unicode letter or digit, `_` and some other special chars (like diacritics). What do you want?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly as you have described, yet the debugger shows me m.Success = true. I will try to implement it in SQL. I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, due to which `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])` is the same as `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` and only requires any 1 ASCII letter, lower- or uppercase.

Besides, `[a-zA-Z0-9\S]` = `\S` as letters and digits are all non-whitespace chars.

Also, you must trim the string on both ends, use `.Trim()`, not `.TrimEnd()`.

Besides, it is advisable to use the principle of [constrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) in password regexes to make them more efficient.

Use

string pattern = @"^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=\w*\W)\S{8,}$";
   Match m = Regex.Match(passwordToCheck.Trim(), pattern);

**Explanation**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - there must be at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - there must be at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=\D*\d)` - there must be at least 1 digit
- `(?=\w*\W)` - there must be at least 1 non-word char
- `\S{8,}` - 8 or more non-whitespace chars (no spaces, but accept all other chars)
- `$` - end of string.